# Redirect URL on OAuth2.0 after switching from http to https

Tags: https, oauth

I'm pretty new to Google OAuth 2.0 config and please allow me to ask this question.

I have a wordpress site which protocol will be updated to `https` from `http`. On the site, it pulls data from google api with using OAuth 2.0 with 'http://*' as redirect url.

After making the site protocol https, I am going to add redirect setting on wordpress server side from `http` to `https`.

My question is whether google api data will be still available on my wordpress site without updating redirect url on OAuth 2.0 since the server side handles redirect. I know I need to update the OAuth 2.0 redirect url to `https` eventually. The reason I'm asking this is I would like to keep pulling google api data without failing right after switching to `https` before updating the protocol on OAuth.

Answer (score 0):

As the result of this, I did not have to update the redirect url on OAuth 2.0 page.
I guess it works because I added redirect on WordPress, then the request to the page was redirected to 'https' automatically.